# Is the relation R={(a,b),(c,b)} transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am confused because at university we learned that a relationship is transitive if (a,b) ∈ R  and (b,c) ∈ R then (a,c) ∈ R. But what if there are only two elements, in particular (a,b) and (c,b)?

Comment: yes it is transitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of transitivity says that *whenever* $x \mathrel{R} y$ and $y \mathrel{R} z$ then it must be $x \mathrel{R} z$. In your case there is no triple that satisfies the antecedent (before "then"), so it is (vacuously) true.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is transitive, vacuously.